# RMarkdown - HTML generated files without markdown styling

Tags: html, r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I have installed RMarkdown package in my R-Studio and I want to knit into HTML format. After knitting any .rmd file (including the default code created after starting a new Rmd file), the output html file does not include any markdown styling. See the picture of the generated html file on my computer here:

[image: Generated HTML File with undesired styling]

As you can see for example, the font is set as plain Times New Roman and also the way the dataframes are displayed does not look like the usual markdown-style.

Please, how can I get the HTML file styled as an usual markdown file?
Note: I did not modify the markdown.css file in the library's folder.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your output looks exactly as it should

Comment: I am afraid it does not. Here is my colleague's output of the very same file (please see the differences in fonts or dataframe styling in comparison to the screenshot included above):
https://imgur.com/a/AcGm0jh

Comment: What are the yaml options you passed at the beginning of the file?

Comment: I notice you don't have author/date, so did you modified the YAML header?

Comment: I did not modify the YAML header. This is how the .Rmd file looks like just after creating a new one: [link](https://imgur.com/a/JmWfJq0)
The HTML output then looks exactly as the one I included above.
Note: When inserting the author/date parameters in the YAML header manually, they will appear in the generated file, but the graphical styling of the whole document will remain unchanged.